# Различия между функциями calloc и malloc

Tags: c, функции, память, malloc, calloc

В чем заключается отличие функции malloc от calloc?
Есть ли случаи, когда подходит лишь одна из этих функций?

Comment: Почему бы вам не почитать описание этих функций самостоятельно?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Во-первых, функция `calloc`, в отличие от `malloc`, возвращает указатель на *инициализированный* блок памяти, т.е. изначально содержащий нулевые биты<sup>1</sup>. Это, однако, совсем не означает, что функция `calloc` сама занимается обнулением полученного блока памяти в контексте пользовательского процесса. Функция `calloc` может пользоваться более эффективными средствами обнуления, предоставляемыми подлежащей платформой, т.е., например, выделять память в пуле "обнуленных страниц" ОС или использовать некий механизм "ленивого" обнуления уровня аппаратуры/ОС. То есть если вам нужен обнуленный блок памяти, то в общем случае получение такого блока памяти через `calloc` может оказаться [существенно более эффективной операцией](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc), чем "ручное" обнуление блока памяти, полученного через `malloc`.

Во-вторых, функция `calloc`, как несложно заметить, сама внутренне занимается вычислением общего размера запрашиваемого блока памяти (буквально - перемножением своих аргументов). При этом функция `calloc` обязана самостоятельно отследить корректность такого перемножения, т.е. обнаружить ошибку при возникновении переполнения. В случае использования функции `malloc` такое перемножение (если оно необходимо) выполняет вызывающий код и предотвращение переполнения - обязанность вызывающего кода.

---

<sup>1</sup> С точки зрения языка это не гарантирует правильное формирование нулевых указателей и нулевых значений плавающего типа.

Answer (score 7):

`malloc` просто выделяет память, оставляя ее содержимое неопределенным, a `calloc` ее гарантированно обнуляет. Что не всегда необходимо, зато требует времени...